# Shorter form of this expression: const show = condition ? false : undefined

Tags: javascript

Is there a shorter way to write the expression below in JavaScript

```js
const show = condition ? false : undefined
```

Comment: Why would you want to make it shorter? 
It is important to write code that can be easily readable by others.

Comment: I guess this one is the shortest for both conditions either `true` or `false`.

Answer (score 0):

You said that if `condition` is true `show` must be `false` and if `condition` is false then `show` must be `undefined`.

The answer for `Is there a shorter way` is **NO** because of converting `true` to false and false to `undefined`. You already find shortest way of doing that :)

```
const show = condition ? false : undefined
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do

```
const show = !condition && undefined;
```

but this is not necessarily any better.